# Android parsing of specific text to perform action on click

Tags: android

First of all I have no clue how to describe what I ask for or if it is possible.

So my main question is if it is possible and how.

As example: In texts (emails/ memos/ whtsapp) you can click on parts of the text (like hyperlinks/ numbers/ email addresses) and it will call an application handling this.

Is it possible to add for example an recognition of dates?

I think of writing a text that contains "7:25" and with one click it sends you to your calendar or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.  But it's complicated.

There is a utility class called `android.util.Linkify` that will scan through text and match to things like: phone numbers, street addresses, email address and web URLs.  It then turns them into links and puts the whole text with the links into your `TextView`.  So for those types of links it's easy to use.

Unfortunately, there isn't built-in logic to scan for calendar dates or times.  You would have to add that logic yourself.  You have to come up with a regular expression that matches the dates or times or whatever you want to link, and give that to the `Linkify` utility using a `MatchFilter`.

Also, consider that you will not just be matching the date/time, but since you want to sent an event to a calendar, you would have to parse out the event title from the text along with the date/time.

This is kind of advanced stuff.  If you are just starting out with Android, you should look for an easier project where you can learn more of the basics before tackling something like this and getting yourself completely frustrated.

Comment: I've read a little in the topic. Every application has to take care of it on its own or is there a way to provide this for all apps?

Comment: If the Android system doesn't provide it, then the application has to do it on its own.  There's not really a way that you can make a custom TextView that other apps would use because if there was, that would be a huge security issue.  Now having said that, if you wrote this custom TextView and put it on GitHub for other people to use, they could incorporate it into their app.  But they would actually compile it into their code; that way, they could verify there's no virus in it or anything.  Did that answer your question?